# Heapsort implementation only nearly sorts array

Tags: ruby, algorithm, sorting

I've been trying to implement heapsort in Ruby, but thus far, my algorithm only sorts like 90% of the array correctly and not the rest. Can anyone see what goes wrong?

This is my code

```
require 'pp'

def left(i)
    (i+1)*2-1
end

def right(i)
    (i+1)*2
end

def max_heapify(a, root)
    left, right = left(root), right(root)
    max = root
    if left < a.length and a[left] > a[max]
        max = left
    end
    if right < a.length and a[right] > a[max]
        max = right
    end
    if max != root
        a[root], a[max] = a[max], a[root]
        max_heapify(a, max)
    else
        a
    end
end

def build_max_heap(a)
    ((a.size-1)/2).downto(0) do |i|
        max_heapify(a, i)
    end
    a
end

def heap_sort(a)
    len = a.size
    build_max_heap(a)
    (len-1).downto(0) do |i|
        a[0], a[i] = a[i], a[0]
        a.delete_at(len)
        max_heapify(a, 0)
    end 
    a
end

a = (1..10).to_a.shuffle
pp heap_sort(a)
```

result: `[10, 9, 7, 8, 6, 2, 4, 5, 1, 3]`

Answer (score -1):

During the sort, when you move the max element to the end, don't touch it anymore, it is
sorted and the array to sort (and the heap) should end just before it.

You need one more parameter to `max_heapify`, to tell where the heap ends, it's not the
end of the array.

```
require 'pp'

def left(i)
    i*2+1
end

def right(i)
    i*2+2
end

def max_heapify(a, root, len)
    left, right = left(root), right(root)
    max = root
    if left < len and a[left] > a[max]
        max = left
    end
    if right < len and a[right] > a[max]
        max = right
    end
    if max != root
        a[root], a[max] = a[max], a[root]
        max_heapify(a, max, len)
    else
        a
    end
end

def build_max_heap(a)
    ((a.size-1)/2).downto(0) do |i|
        max_heapify(a, i, a.length)
    end
    a
end

def heap_sort(a)
    len = a.size
    build_max_heap(a)
    (len-1).downto(0) do |i|
        a[0], a[i] = a[i], a[0]
        max_heapify(a, 0, i)
    end
    a
end

a = (1..10).to_a.shuffle
pp heap_sort(a)
```

PP. Not sure what `delete_at` does (don't know Ruby), but I strongly suspect it's not
needed, during a sort you don't "delete" anything from the array, you just rearrange elements.